# Need Advice With Music Website Logic / Display Issue

Tags: php, mysql, logic

i'v been scratching my head all day trying to figure out how to display duets on my music website.

basically i have 2 tables in my MySQL database.

`singers` : singer_id, singer_name.

`songs`   : singer_id, song_id, song_name.

i display the songs like so:
`singer_name`:`song_name`

i know i can make another table called finder with just: `singer_id` and `song_id`
and if there is a duet i can just add the song to two singers.
but is this the best solution?

isnt there a better more clever solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is fine but you shouldn't maintain two separate mechanisms to store the singer. I.e., drop the singer_id field from the songs table:

```
singers: singer_id, singer_name
songs: song_id, song_name
performers: song_id, singer_id
```

This lets you easily find all songs for a singer:

```
select song_id from performers where singer_id = $id;
```

And all singers for a song:

```
select singer_id from performers where song_id = $id;
```

Comment: thanks @alexhowansky but is this the best solution, or the best solution is what brad said, just getting a mysql book explaining relational database and one to many relationships.? because i have more tables for singers: albums, news, videos.. and more.

Comment: This solution is essentially the same as the one Brad suggested, it's the standard accepted way to handle these types of relations. Basically, you're going to want a table for each entity (songs, albums, singers, etc.) plus one table for each one-to-many relationship (singers on a song, songs on an album, etc.)

Comment: can u please edit your post to show me the basic connection between the tables? please.., thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-work your schema so that you can have a one-to-many relationship between the song and singers.

Easiest way to do this is to add a third table called `singers_songs`, with two columns, `singer_id`, and `song_id`.  (Set them both to be the PK.)

Most of your songs will have one record in that third table, but for songs with multiple singers, there will be multiple records.

Comment: thanks, what book explaining one-to-many relationship would you recommend?